# Show loader when page loads hide when it finish loading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to create a plugin to show an animated loader when page loads and when page loads finished want to show another loader, basically like `fade in` /`fade out`. is there any function prebuilts in wordprees. like : `loadbefore loadAfter`

Comment: You have to write your own function using JS/jQuery. WordPress is PHP based CMS which won't help you accomplish that effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994600/loading-screen-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading screen using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994600/loading-screen-using-jquery)

Comment: Similar question has already been answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906956/show-loading-icon-until-the-page-is-load