# Add a loading image when using jquery.mmenu plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, mmenu

I have tryed all the suggestions but none seem to work with this plugin. I am not using a ajax call, the delay is due to some data map rendering issue.

I followed this method: http://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/

Altough I add the div tag at the very begining of my html, when I debug the code I saw it after many div tags that belongs for the plugin. Summed it up, it isn't at the top of the html.

The .js and the .css are the same in the example.

So I have

html

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

css

```
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('images/page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

js

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
```

Side note: I tryed to replace fadeOut for hide().

This method isn't working, thanks

Comment: I am closer, but it doesn't work yet. I followed this example, but the gif never gets hidden. It's always visible.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853662/how-to-show-page-loading-div-until-the-page-has-finished-loading

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use:

`("#loading").fadeOut("slow");`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. if you want check this bicimapuy2.herokuapp.com, there's the code

Comment: Indeed I don't see any differences from what I did. The main one is that I have a lot of code and not only the one of the example.  I render a map, a menu, etc

Comment: Thanks, I put hide() in a previous version with the same result. I not with my laptop right now. I will check it tomorrow and then I will be able to say something new..(I hope).

Comment: Actually now it's working with the last example, either with hide() or fadeOut. Thanks a lot for your help.