# I want to show loading indicator whenever a server request happens from my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web

My requirement is I have an ASP.NET web page which is taking some time for loading first time because it has a custom control(ascx) of grid and some other buttons. Also I have some other buttons,check boxes, print reports (ssrs report) in my web page, on click of which it will take some time to process and comeback with result. So my requirement is whenever my page load first time or any server request process I want to show loading indicator to the client user by restricting any other action in the page until the result come up and page is ready.

Comment: I have a solution but looking for better solution (my manager asked whether I am sure that it is the best solution?).

Comment: My solution was to have a modal spinner, that on a button press, showed the spinner until the page refreshed.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853662/how-to-show-page-loading-div-until-the-page-has-finished-loading](Look at this question and answers) Since you didnt provide any code we are guessing what you have achieved so far. And cant help you to solve your problem

Comment: @RickBronger my question was self explanatory which doesn't  required any code as it is common issue for all the sites. But when I searched I got bit n pieces and some complicated result like AJAX codes and some confusing server side solutions. But your stack over flow link was helpful. But it also needs some fine tuning like eliminating gif image in the div and adding the same as part of background image in a class which we can apply to that div.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same solution as that already mentioned in [How to show Page Loading div until the page has finished loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853662/how-to-show-page-loading-div-until-the-page-has-finished-loading) which already there in stack over flow. But in first research I haven't seen these answer that s  why I put this question. I hope it is the best solution so far.