# using fadeOut() or hide() to fade/hide Bootstrap 4 spinner/loader when browser window is completely loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

**THE AIM**

I would like to show a spinner/loader until the window of the browser loads completely and after that, it must fade/hide.

**ATTEMPTS**

I've tried a jQuery code suggested in another question ([How to show Page Loading div until the page has finished loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853662/how-to-show-page-loading-div-until-the-page-has-finished-loading)) which is shown below. Additionally, I've also tried not using Bootstrap and use https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders instead as suggested in the same question.

**THE PROBLEM**

None of the above gives me the result that I need as the spinner/loader shows above the content of my page and doesn't fade/hide.

**SUMMARY**

I would like to know what I might be missing.

Thanks for your help!

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  //$(".spinner-border").fadeOut("slow");
  $(".spinner-border").hide();
});
```

```css
.images {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}

.spinner-border {
  color: #d4d4d4;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="spinner-border"></div>

<h2>Gallery</h2>

<img src="img-1.jpg" class="images">
<img src="img-2.jpg" class="images">
<img src="img-3.jpg" class="images">
```

Comment: There's an error in the console. This is because `load()` is used to make an AJAX request to *add content to the page*. To hook to the `load` event of the window use `$(window).on('load', function() {...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi JoeHat I solved it like this (see codepen), works with bootstrap 4 and Jquery 3.4.1. Couldn't get it to work until I used Jquery below. Also added a timer.

Here's [a link] https://codepen.io/pieperrr/pen/PowBjZO

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {      
  setTimeout(function() {
 $('.overlay-loader').fadeOut(function() {           
    });
    }, 5000);            
});
```

Comment: Use it when load/refresh Bootstrap table which takes some time depending on the data

Comment: Your code, here on Stack Overflow, produces an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'`. The Codepen looks fine. I would also recommend using Codepen's "Tidy JS" feature; it's under the dropdown.