# Using 'overflow: hidden' (CSS) and jQuery to prevent user from scrolling though a loading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow, document-body

**AIM**

I would like to prevent the user from scrolling while the page is loading.

**PROBLEM**

The code below does work, and it does prevent the user from scrolling when using:

```
$('body').toggleClass('hidden');

.hidden {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

HOWEVER, it only seems to prevent the user from scrolling during the extra 2 seconds of the loader animation.

**ATTEMPT**

I essentially took the code from this question [How to show Page Loading div until the page has finished loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853662/how-to-show-page-loading-div-until-the-page-has-finished-loading).

```
$('body').append('<div style="" id="loadingDiv"><div class="loader"></div></div>');

$(window).on('load', function() {
  $( "#loadingDiv" ).show();
  setTimeout(removeLoader, 2000); //wait for page load PLUS two seconds.
  $('body').toggleClass('hidden');
});

function removeLoader() {
  $("#loadingDiv").fadeOut(1500, function() {
    // fadeOut complete. Remove the loading div
    $("#loadingDiv").hide(); //makes page more lightweight
    $('body').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
}
```

**SUMMARY**

I would like to prevent the user from scrolling the page during the whole process of loading, i.e. while the page is loading AND for the extra two seconds of the loading animation.

**UPDATE**

For a clearer picture of the effect see the snippet below:

```js
  $('body').append('<div style="" id="loadingDiv"><div class="loader"></div></div>');

  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $( "#loadingDiv" ).show();
    setTimeout(removeLoader, 2000); //wait for page load PLUS two seconds.
    $('body').toggleClass('hidden');
  });

  function removeLoader() {
    $("#loadingDiv").fadeOut(1500, function() {
      // fadeOut complete. Remove the loading div
      $("#loadingDiv").hide(); //makes page more lightweight
      $('body').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
  }
```

```css
.hidden {
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .loader,
    .loader:before,
    .loader:after {
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 1.5em;
      height: 1.5em;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
      -webkit-animation: load7 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
      animation: load7 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
    }

    .loader {
      color: red;
      font-size: 10px;
      margin: 80px auto;
      position: relative;
      text-indent: -9999em;
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
      transform: translateZ(0);
      -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
      animation-delay: -0.16s;
    }

    .loader:before,
    .loader:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }

    .loader:before {
      left: -3.5em;
      -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
      animation-delay: -0.32s;
    }

    .loader:after {
      left: 3.5em;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes load7 {

      0%,
      80%,
      100% {
        box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 -1.3em;
      }

      40% {
        box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 0;
      }
    }

    @keyframes load7 {

      0%,
      80%,
      100% {
        box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 -1.3em;
      }

      40% {
        box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 0;
      }
    }

    #loadingDiv {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #000;

      display: -webkit-flexbox;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>My Custom Loader</h2>
  <img src="https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="">
  <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/micro-peacock-feather-hd-imagebest-260nw-1127238584.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2019_41/3047866/191010-japan-stalker-mc-1121_06b4c20bbf96a51dc8663f334404a899.fit-760w.JPG" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/fall-1072821__340.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: Why do you think `$("#loadingDiv").hide();` makes the page more lightweight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are insistent use this approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').addClass('loader');
    
    $(window).on('load', function() {
      setTimeout(function(){$('body').removeClass('loader');}, 2000);

    });
    
});
```

```css
body{
    width: 100%;height: 500px;background: red;overflow: auto;
}
.loader{
    overflow: hidden !important;width: 100%;height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Body</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget about overflow and hiding the `body`. Just disable scrolling prior to the `body` tag by setting `window.scrollTo(0,0)` and then re-enable it in the `load` event by removing that event handler.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Disable Scroll Until Page is Loaded</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Disable scrolling initially
    $(window).on("scroll", preventScroll);
    
    // Once window is loaded...
    $(window).on("load", function(){ 
      // Wait 2 more seconds...
      setTimeout(function(){
        // Re-enable the scroll by removing the previously 
        // added event handler that cancelled it.
        $(window).off("scroll", preventScroll);
        $("#loadingDiv").fadeOut(1500); // fade out the loading image
      }, 2000);
    });
    
    function preventScroll(){
      window.scrollTo(0, 0); // Effectively cancells scrolling
    }
    
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="loadingDiv" src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/52qtwCtj9OLTi/giphy.gif">
  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per et quas tation dissentias, ad usu illud efficiendi scribentur. Vim at ullum elitr, labores evertitur eum eu, vim urbanitas moderatius an. In sit meliore percipitur, mnesarchum quaerendum ex sed, mel graecis cotidieque conclusionemque in. Aeque graeci dolorum vim in, ea iuvaret inimicus efficiantur vis. Id mea utinam detracto, eam repudiandae definitiones no. In facilis ceteros salutatus eos.

Per aperiri expetendis cu. Mel ea exerci tractatos, his te mollis cotidieque, et nec dicit ignota aperiri. Magna repudiare sententiae mea no, pri te cetero vidisse antiopam, ut sea legere essent. Mea aliquam qualisque ut.

Ad cum diam petentium scribentur, sit te detraxit contentiones, ludus dignissim eam id. Quidam alienum id eam. Enim tota nusquam an per, ius invenire interpretaris necessitatibus at. Nam stet iisque ceteros ut.

Utamur oportere duo ne. Ea adhuc forensibus vis, alii virtute mel at, amet harum mel cu. Eos an ullum aliquando theophrastus. Ei sed laoreet quaestio interpretaris, per error nihil expetendis cu, duo graece iuvaret alienum ne.

Vel posse blandit molestie in, vix no porro iuvaret antiopam. Usu in falli antiopam definiebas, choro tacimates usu te. Equidem scribentur deterruisset at est, sed an harum quaestio laboramus. Erat debitis vix id. Ipsum feugait theophrastus te per, vitae civibus eum ei.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per et quas tation dissentias, ad usu illud efficiendi scribentur. Vim at ullum elitr, labores evertitur eum eu, vim urbanitas moderatius an. In sit meliore percipitur, mnesarchum quaerendum ex sed, mel graecis cotidieque conclusionemque in. Aeque graeci dolorum vim in, ea iuvaret inimicus efficiantur vis. Id mea utinam detracto, eam repudiandae definitiones no. In facilis ceteros salutatus eos.

Per aperiri expetendis cu. Mel ea exerci tractatos, his te mollis cotidieque, et nec dicit ignota aperiri. Magna repudiare sententiae mea no, pri te cetero vidisse antiopam, ut sea legere essent. Mea aliquam qualisque ut.

Ad cum diam petentium scribentur, sit te detraxit contentiones, ludus dignissim eam id. Quidam alienum id eam. Enim tota nusquam an per, ius invenire interpretaris necessitatibus at. Nam stet iisque ceteros ut.

Utamur oportere duo ne. Ea adhuc forensibus vis, alii virtute mel at, amet harum mel cu. Eos an ullum aliquando theophrastus. Ei sed laoreet quaestio interpretaris, per error nihil expetendis cu, duo graece iuvaret alienum ne.

Vel posse blandit molestie in, vix no porro iuvaret antiopam. Usu in falli antiopam definiebas, choro tacimates usu te. Equidem scribentur deterruisset at est, sed an harum quaestio laboramus. Erat debitis vix id. Ipsum feugait theophrastus te per, vitae civibus eum ei.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per et quas tation dissentias, ad usu illud efficiendi scribentur. Vim at ullum elitr, labores evertitur eum eu, vim urbanitas moderatius an. In sit meliore percipitur, mnesarchum quaerendum ex sed, mel graecis cotidieque conclusionemque in. Aeque graeci dolorum vim in, ea iuvaret inimicus efficiantur vis. Id mea utinam detracto, eam repudiandae definitiones no. In facilis ceteros salutatus eos.

Per aperiri expetendis cu. Mel ea exerci tractatos, his te mollis cotidieque, et nec dicit ignota aperiri. Magna repudiare sententiae mea no, pri te cetero vidisse antiopam, ut sea legere essent. Mea aliquam qualisque ut.

Ad cum diam petentium scribentur, sit te detraxit contentiones, ludus dignissim eam id. Quidam alienum id eam. Enim tota nusquam an per, ius invenire interpretaris necessitatibus at. Nam stet iisque ceteros ut.

Utamur oportere duo ne. Ea adhuc forensibus vis, alii virtute mel at, amet harum mel cu. Eos an ullum aliquando theophrastus. Ei sed laoreet quaestio interpretaris, per error nihil expetendis cu, duo graece iuvaret alienum ne.

Vel posse blandit molestie in, vix no porro iuvaret antiopam. Usu in falli antiopam definiebas, choro tacimates usu te. Equidem scribentur deterruisset at est, sed an harum quaestio laboramus. Erat debitis vix id. Ipsum feugait theophrastus te per, vitae civibus eum ei.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per et quas tation dissentias, ad usu illud efficiendi scribentur. Vim at ullum elitr, labores evertitur eum eu, vim urbanitas moderatius an. In sit meliore percipitur, mnesarchum quaerendum ex sed, mel graecis cotidieque conclusionemque in. Aeque graeci dolorum vim in, ea iuvaret inimicus efficiantur vis. Id mea utinam detracto, eam repudiandae definitiones no. In facilis ceteros salutatus eos.

Per aperiri expetendis cu. Mel ea exerci tractatos, his te mollis cotidieque, et nec dicit ignota aperiri. Magna repudiare sententiae mea no, pri te cetero vidisse antiopam, ut sea legere essent. Mea aliquam qualisque ut.

Ad cum diam petentium scribentur, sit te detraxit contentiones, ludus dignissim eam id. Quidam alienum id eam. Enim tota nusquam an per, ius invenire interpretaris necessitatibus at. Nam stet iisque ceteros ut.

Utamur oportere duo ne. Ea adhuc forensibus vis, alii virtute mel at, amet harum mel cu. Eos an ullum aliquando theophrastus. Ei sed laoreet quaestio interpretaris, per error nihil expetendis cu, duo graece iuvaret alienum ne.

Vel posse blandit molestie in, vix no porro iuvaret antiopam. Usu in falli antiopam definiebas, choro tacimates usu te. Equidem scribentur deterruisset at est, sed an harum quaestio laboramus. Erat debitis vix id. Ipsum feugait theophrastus te per, vitae civibus eum ei.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per et quas tation dissentias, ad usu illud efficiendi scribentur. Vim at ullum elitr, labores evertitur eum eu, vim urbanitas moderatius an. In sit meliore percipitur, mnesarchum quaerendum ex sed, mel graecis cotidieque conclusionemque in. Aeque graeci dolorum vim in, ea iuvaret inimicus efficiantur vis. Id mea utinam detracto, eam repudiandae definitiones no. In facilis ceteros salutatus eos.

Per aperiri expetendis cu. Mel ea exerci tractatos, his te mollis cotidieque, et nec dicit ignota aperiri. Magna repudiare sententiae mea no, pri te cetero vidisse antiopam, ut sea legere essent. Mea aliquam qualisque ut.

Ad cum diam petentium scribentur, sit te detraxit contentiones, ludus dignissim eam id. Quidam alienum id eam. Enim tota nusquam an per, ius invenire interpretaris necessitatibus at. Nam stet iisque ceteros ut.

Utamur oportere duo ne. Ea adhuc forensibus vis, alii virtute mel at, amet harum mel cu. Eos an ullum aliquando theophrastus. Ei sed laoreet quaestio interpretaris, per error nihil expetendis cu, duo graece iuvaret alienum ne.

Vel posse blandit molestie in, vix no porro iuvaret antiopam. Usu in falli antiopam definiebas, choro tacimates usu te. Equidem scribentur deterruisset at est, sed an harum quaestio laboramus. Erat debitis vix id. Ipsum feugait theophrastus te per, vitae civibus eum ei.

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks! This does work. However, I would like to keep my original animation effect. Instead of minimizing the loader in the top left corner as it fades, I would like the loader to simply fade away... How could this be done with your code?

Comment: @Joehat I changed the method from `hide()` to `fadeOut()`, which does what you are looking for. Just swap the animated .gif I used with your component.