# SetTimeout Loader Animation Site

Tags: javascript, animation, loader

I want to add loader on my site when I load the site then I set up the SetTimeout for 2 secs then I add the hidden class, but somehow it won't work, any ideas?

```js
const preLoader = document.getElementById('preloader');

function loaderSite() {
  preLoader.classList.add('hidden');
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  setTimeout(loaderSite, 2500);
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="" id="preloader">
  <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
<div clas="navbar"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show Page Loading div until the page has finished loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853662/how-to-show-page-loading-div-until-the-page-has-finished-loading)

Answer (score 0):

It's working, brother.

```js
const preLoader = document.getElementById('preloader');

function loaderSite() {
  preLoader.classList.add('hidden');
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  setTimeout(loaderSite, 2500);
}, false);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="" id="preloader">
  <div id="loader">Loading</div>
</div>
<div clas="navbar"></div>
```

Comment: weird, in my vscode it doesn't work

Comment: Run your code in the browser and see if it works or not.