# Add loading image after click the `register` button in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in Laravel and using Laravel version 8 now.

There is form submit in register page.

When user fills out their info and clicks the `register` button, another app is deployed to new server.
so deploy api is called after clicking `resgister` button.

As you know, there are some times to deploy to new server after clicking button.
So in this case, I'd like to add loading image.

register form is in `register.blade.php` and api calls and register actions are in register controller.

Here are some parts of code.

```
@extends('layouts.central')

@section('content')

<div>
    <div class="mt-8 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md">
        <div class="px-4 py-8 bg-white shadow sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
            <form action="{{ route('central.tenants.register.submit') }}" method="POST">

                <div class="mt-6">
                    <label for="name" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 leading-5">
                        Full name
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="mt-6">
                    <label for="domain" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 leading-5">
                        Domain
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="mt-6">
                    <label for="email" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 leading-5">
                        Email address
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="mt-6">
                    <label for="password" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 leading-5">
                        Password
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="mt-6">
                    <label for="password_confirmation" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 leading-5">
                        Confirm Password
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="mt-6">
                    <span class="block w-full rounded-md shadow-sm">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">
                            Register
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

This is RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Central;

use App\Actions\CreateTenantAction;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Tenant;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        return view('central.register');
    } 

    public function submit(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $this->validate($request, [
            'domain' => 'required|string|unique:domains',
            'company' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:tenants',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|max:255',
        ]);

       ....

        here are api calls for deploying to new server

        $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
        $tenant = (new CreateTenantAction)($data, $data['domain']);


        return redirect()->away("http://{$siteDomain}");
    }
}
```

In this case, where do i have to add loading section?
Don't need to add any code in `controller.php` ?

Could you make or add the correct answer in my code?
Thanks a lot and appreciate.

Comment: you need to add them in blade file, right after the button is clicked

Comment: @Psycho
can you show me some examples or can you add it on my code?

Comment: Kindly have a look at the ajax post request, you can show an image when the response is sent and hide it when the response return from the server. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853662/how-to-show-page-loading-div-until-the-page-has-finished-loading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to any of your root css files or header style of root layout:

***CSS***

```css
#loader {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75) url("/your_loading_image.gif") no-repeat center center;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

add this div to any of your root layout like app layout or master layout:

***html***

```html
<div id='loader'></div>
```

Then in your register page, add jquery code script to the bottom:

***script***

```js
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "form" ).submit(function() {
        $('#loader').show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks. it works for me and you saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

I thought to add my Idea for this and its working perfectly after testing

The HTML part

```
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg submit" type="submit">
<span class="btn-txt">SUBMIT</span>
<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm d-none" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>                 
 </button>
```

Then in JQuery :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#clientform").submit(function() {
                $(".spinner-border").removeClass("d-none");
                $(".submit").attr("disabled", true);
                $(".btn-txt").text("Processing ...");
            });
```

Let me explain whats going . We added a span having a class of bootrap spinner which is by default hidden.
Added a class to span .btn-txt on submit button text.
Then in Jquery on form submit having an id we are removing class "d-none", disabling the button and adding the processing... text to .btn-txt class.

I hope I have explained in clear words.